# Erratic increment in Mysql Auto increment column

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am seeing `AUTO_INCREMENT` column of MySql table having erratically large values. 
Somehow I am trying to understand how can this situation occur so as to avoid it.

Current scenarios:

1. Multiple tables are residing each with single `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns. All are having this issue.
2. I am doing frequent batch commit across tables. Can that be culprit ?
3. There are 2 databases on same mysql server. Can that interfere ?

I tried to read and understand [mysql auto_increment doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) and figured out batch commit can be problem. But I am not sure as what `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` should I switch to ?

Snapshot of erratic increment in values.

[image]

All MySql system variables are default and unchanged.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many tables with `auto_increment` columns you have in a single data base. Either, it doesn't matter how many data bases you have in your server. So, yes - scenario no. 2 is causing the problem.

Comment: If you're doing `INSERT IGNORE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it will increment the ID whenever it skips an insert. This can create lots of gaps like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there really gaps of thousands?

I have seen such in a "normalization" table that used `INSERT IGNORE` to either add an entry or silently do nothing.  The trouble is that "doing nothing" includes allocating an auto_inc id, but not using it.

IODKU, ROLLBACK, and a few other things also "burn" ids.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table discusses a non-burning way to do normalization at a high rate.

Another thing that can happen... Since the id is not visible to other threads until `COMMIT` is done, other threads may see a gap, then later see the missing id.  This can be annoying for using MySQL as a queuing mechanism and you are "continuing where you left off".

Comment: Thanks `on duplicate key update` was the culprit for me.

Comment: Alas, IODKU would be such a beautiful statement, but for the burned ids.  In the link, it shows a more clumsy `INSERT ... SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ...`, `SELECT` discovers the missing rows, and then `INSERT` inserts only those (without burning ids).